# Intercepting when a page is requested

Tags: event-subscribers

I am trying to call a function every time a page is loaded. With Drupal 7, I used hook_init, now I'm using a subscribed event.

```
  public function logRegEntry(GetResponseEvent $event) {
    $request = $event->getRequest();
    $method = $request->getMethod();
    $path = $request->getPathInfo();
    $route_name = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName();
    if (($method == 'GET') && ($path == '/')) {
      // do it just for this module
      \Drupal::service('wdocsDebug')->logSiteEntry();
    }
  }
```

This works fine for the home page, but I want it for every page a user requests. This is getting called four times; first for the page I'm requestings, and then for:
/admin/coffee/get-data
/history/5/read
/quickedit/attachments

I did notice that on the first request, the $route_name is set to "entity.node.canonical" -- might this be a better way to check for a page? Probably not, since it would only get triggered by node pages.

I'm looking for a better way to do this, not sure why there are four request events. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your event subscriber is also picking up AJAX requests (e.g. `/admin/coffee/get-data` is an endpoint the Coffee module uses when it's needed in the client browser) which explains why you're seeing multiple events for a page request.

You can filter out those events with the logic best fits your needs (e.g. a [`$request->isXmlHttpRequest()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21http-foundation%21Request.php/function/Request%3A%3AisXmlHttpRequest/9.0.x) call to check for AJAX requests, or a route whitelist as you mentioned).

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for.